# canvas.drawBitmap draws nothing if supplied with rotation matrix

Tags: android, android-camera, android-canvas

One activity in my application takes pictures, then calls another activity that opens the pictures for editing. Problem is, I can't get the picture I've taken to show up in my canvas the right way.

Structure is like so:

#### Layout

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <SurfaceView id="the_surface_view" />
    <Other_Stuff />
</RelativeLayout>
```

#### Activity

```
class EditorActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private Bitmap image;
    private Matrix rotationMatrix;
    ...
    public void onCreate(){
        ...
        SurfaceView surface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.the_surface_view);
        SurfaceHolder holder = surface.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        editor.setWillNotDraw(false);

        String imageFile = getIntent.getStringExtra("file");
        image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile);

        rotationMatrix = new Matrix();
        rotationMatrix.postRotate(90); 
        // same angle as the camera preview, will be dynamic later
        ...
    }

    protected void onDraw(canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawRGB(255,0,255); // just to make sure that it works
        canvas.drawBitmap(image, rotationMatrix, null);
    }

    @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Canvas canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (holder){
                onDraw(canvas);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "failed canvas lock.",e);
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null){
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

All that happens with this is that the canvas turns magenta.
Weirdly, when I comment out `canvas.postRotation(90)`, the image shows up (albeit with the wrong rotation).

How do I get my image to show up correctly?

Comment: Why not just call canvas.rotate(90, canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2); before calling canvas.drawBitmap so that the canvas will rotate from its center when rendering the bitmap. No need for the matrix

Comment: What happens if you use a smaller value for the rotation? I'm wondering if you're rotating from a corner and essentially rotating it completely off the screen.

Comment: @fadden I've not tried with smaller values, but I reasoned that if 90 degrees rotated it off the screen, then 270 should do the opposite. I realized as I was writing this that I'd done that completely wrong, so I'm going to go try that out.